# Convert docx to mediawiki and preserve [[Image:]]

Tags: converters, mediawiki, docx, libreoffice, soffice

Currently, I'm trying to move a docx to a mediawiki file and preserve the proper filenames in the [[Image:]] tags. For some reason, the proper image file gets swallowed (ie, normally it'd be `media/image4.jpg`, but instead it's just empty).

I've tried extracting the docx and looking at `docx/word/_rels/document.xml.rels` but I have no idea how to figure out what images are duplicated. I made a simple script to do some find/replace, but in one file I have 130 [[Image:]] tags and only 105 images.

As such, I would like to have the MediaWiki filter output the proper image name when doing this:

```
soffice --headless --convert-to txt:MediaWiki myfile.docx
```

I'm on ubuntu 14.10.

Is this possible?

Comment: Why can't you just embed the images in the document file? (Personally I'd also use a proper document format like OpenDocument odt.)

Comment: Because this was a corporate task, converting lots of old docs to mediawiki format. They had to be taken as-is and converted correctly, which I eventually managed (see my answer).

Comment: Ah. From both question and answer it's not *so* clear that you are converting the documents to wikitext pages.

Comment: @Nemo I had suspected that "convert from docx to mediawiki" would have been plainly descriptive there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't appear to be possible, but I have written a workaround found [here](https://gist.github.com/seiyria/42fd07d5bb585b76408e) that solves it. The long and short of it is that I convert the file and manage uploading / linking of images manually.